# how to specify type of some variable, so that it could have value property?

Tags: typescript, typeof

I assume that variable *num* could be string and number, and it's OK with first two if-else cases. But I got an error in console.log line: **property value doesn't exist on type never.**

```
type Num = string | number
const num: Num = 10 as Num

if (typeof num === 'string') {
    num.toLowerCase() // ok
} else if (typeof num === 'number') {
    num.toPrecision(2) // ok
} else {
    console.log(num.value.toLowerCase()) // error
}
```

I don't get it. What type should be num not to get a mistake? Should I use generics?

Comment: If it has a `value` property, then what type is it? Define that type. Use that type as one of the possible types of `Num`.

Comment: I assume the variable could also be an object and then, 'value' should exist on that object type.  still I don't understand, how should I include 'value' key in Num

Comment: Thanks everybody! I solved the issue like this: *type Num = string | number | {value: string}*

Answer (score 0):

The error `Property does not exist on type 'never'` occurs when we try to access a property on a value of type never or when TypeScript gets confused when analyzing our code.

Because you already defined the type of the variable `num` as `Num = string | number`, it should not include any other types except `string` and `number`. Thus, The else statement is redundant, `else statement` would indeed never get evaluated.